# How to redirect a loading message to nul

Tags: windows

I have to use a file several time a month that uses sysinfo. It generates a loading messages that my boss had complaints about. I was asked to fix this. I was lucky to be brought on while still a student. Having said that, I have tried every redirection I know to get the loading message to nul and nothing is working. I went back to my notes from my batchfile class year or so back and remember getting that question wrong because I couldn't figure it out. When I received the fail I remember asking the professor how to do it. She never replied. I don't know if she herself didn't have the answer or was just that bad of an instructor that she would cut us loose out here not knowing what we need.
My question is: How do I redirect a loading message to nul?
example loading message would be the one I am getting from sysinfo.
Windows not Linux.

Thank you

Comment: What's sysinfo? Windows 7 console does not have such command.

Comment: I run it in a batch file. You pipe it with another command. systeminfo | find "host name" /i

Comment: the batchfile holds 13 commands. The load screen hangs around for a while. I can see why I was asked to get rid of it

Comment: Have you tried `systeminfo 2>nul`?

Comment: Could you provide an example(s) of unwanted _loading messages_? Copy it from command window or where they appear, please.

Comment: @MCND this should be an answer, because it's probably the solution to the problem

Comment: C:\Users\Jason>sysinfo
Loading Profile Information ...
This will appear separately 13 times as it is written that many times in the file. I tried systeminfo 2>nul, I don't know I am putting it in the correct place. I put it in the top I just get a blinking courser, in the middle as the first half gets sent to a file nothing changes. I actually went to a professor I had in the first college I went to many years ago in RI and he asked me why I was using the batchfile name in the batchfile. He was getting on by then and don't think he saw the link between the name and the command.

Comment: I tried systeminfo 2>nul. I either got no results or the file did nothing but gave me a blinking cursor. I am not sure where to put the nul. I would post the entire batchfile for you but it is very long. Easiest way to say, the command repeats itself piped into a find 13 times then, CLR, repeated but repeated but redirected into a log. I have out this 2> nul all over and gotten nowhere. Any last bits of advice before I think up another way of writing a way of coming up with this information cleaner?